# Setup issue on Webpack and Typescript(ts-loader)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ts-loader, solid-js

Trying to setup SolidJS with Webpack and ts-loader.

Keep getting an issue on `return` functions.

What exactly am i missing in the loader to solve the issue ?

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
const App = () => {
  // return "Hello World"             // this works!
  return (<div> Hello World </div>)   // this doesnt work!
};
render(App, document.getElementById("app"));
```

**Error Log Output:**

```
> webpack --watch --progress --config webpack.config.js

asset index.js 1.56 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
./src/test.tsx 290 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./src/test.tsx 6:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| const App = () => {
|     // return "Hello World"            // this works!
>     return (<div> Hello World </div>); // this doesnt work!
| };
| render(App, document.getElementById("app"));

webpack 5.47.0 compiled with 1 error in 2081 ms
```

**webpack.config**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/test.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'ts-loader',
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
# tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "solid-js",
   
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": false
  },

  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Have you set up your tsconfig correctly? `"compilerOptions": { "jsx": "preserve", "jsxImportSource": "solid-js",}` as per the [GitHub page](https://github.com/solidjs/solid#quick-start).

Comment: @lawrence-witt actually it was working, basically its started after adding webpack and ts-loader. UPDATED my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

```
#webpack module rules:

module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['solid'],
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
       ]
     }
   ]
},
```

Comment: noob here. What file is that module: stuff in?

Comment: @Phlip its webpack.config

Comment: @Phlip https://github.com/7urkm3n/ChromeExtensionSamples/blob/main/4-reactjs_or_solidjs/webpack/webpack.common_solidjs.js , there's also react version

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Babel. It's fine to preserve the JSX from TypeScript but it still needs to be transformed before it can be finally bundled. babel-preset-solid takes care of this. Otherwise Webpack doesn't know what to do with that JSX.

In general I just use Babel with the TypeScript preset. I know this doesn't give you real time type checking and just strips the types. Create React App uses fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin to solve that problem and processes the type checking in parallel to the Babel transform.

Comment: Thanks, kinda solved adding the `babel-loader` layer before `ts-loader`